# How to fix missing share count on webpages after moving to HTTPS?

Tags: wordpress, facebook

A month ago we moved to the more secure protocol HTTPS by implementing SSL certificates on our websites. We are a media house and write a lot of articles so the share count under our articles is a reliable way for our readers and us to determine if the content is worth reading / writing. After moving to HTTPS all our historical shares were changed to "0" shares - because the canonical URLs for all articles changed to HTTPS - and these URLs had no shares yet. So we did what was adviced and changed all the canonical URLs back to HTTP from the date HTTPS was implemented and configured an og:ttl tag to tell Facebot to scrape our sites every 4th day.

Our issue is we waited for 2 weeks now since changing the canonicals, but there is no change present on our old articles. We can go and manually scrape an article in the debugger and the shares get fixed, but the huge majority of posts on our 10 websites are not fixed and it seems we can't do nothing about it. - This is a big issue, because we also create and offer PR articles on our sites but we can't show them to clients as examples because they can't see any shares on our work from a month ago.

How do we fix this in the shortest time possible please?

This question is going to be asked and an answer needed again and again since more and more websites are moving to HTTPS.

**More information:**

- Our main site is https://www.startitup.sk
- We are using Wordpress for all our websites
- We moved the site to HTTPS around the 9th of January so an article with 0 shares (with HTTPS) would be: https://www.startitup.sk/slovensky-vedec-robert-mistrik-vyvija-spolu-so-svojim-timom-cloudovu-databazu-ktora-buducnosti-zmeni-liecbu-chorob/
- the code we used for changing the canonicals historically is placed in the functions.php file of our theme and is as follows:

```js
/**
 * Check if post was published before SSL was aplied (9th of January 2017) - if yes set canonical url to http not https
 */
function switch_canonicals_before_SSL() {
 global $post;

 $canonical = get_permalink($post->ID);

 // get post write date in Unix timestamp format
 $pubDate = get_the_date( $d='U', $post->ID);
 // 9th of January in Unix timestamp format
 $sslDate = 1484611199;

 // $pubDdate < $sslDate
 if($pubDate < $sslDate) {
  $canonical = str_replace( 'https://www.startitup', 'http://www.startitup', $canonical );
  return $canonical;
 } else {
  return $canonical;
 }
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', 'switch_canonicals_before_SSL' );

/**
* Add og:ttl for Facebot in header
*/
function insert_fb_og_ttl() {
 global $post;
 if ( !is_singular()) //if it is not a post or a page
  return;
        echo '<meta property="og:ttl" content="345600"/>';
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'insert_fb_og_ttl', 5 );
```

Comment: Looks like you failed to implement an exception to the HTTP->HTTPS redirect for the Facebook scraper. Go look at the debug tool result for the example URL you mentioned, and fix the “circular redirect path” issue.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, now that you mention it, it could we our nginx redirection to the secure site. I'll check it right away.